# FileNotFoundError trying naive Bayes algorithm using dataset 20_newspaper

Tags: python

[image]

CODE:

```
X = [] # an element of X is represented as (filename,text)
Y = [] # an element of Y represents the newsgroup category of the corresponding X element
source1 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\foziakhurshid\Desktop\naive bayse/20_newsgroups/")
for category in os.listdir('20_newsgroups'):
    for document in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\foziakhurshid\Desktop\naive bayse/20_newsgroups/'+category):
        with open('20_newsgroups/'+category+'/'+document, "r") as f:
            X.append((document,f.read()))
            Y.append(category)
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-77db388a8724> in <module>
      2 Y = [] # an element of Y represents the newsgroup category of the corresponding X element
      3 source1 = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\foziakhurshid\Desktop\naive bayse/20_newsgroups/")
----> 4 for category in os.listdir('20_newsgroups'):
      5     for document in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\foziakhurshid\Desktop\naive bayse/20_newsgroups/'+category):
      6         with open('20_newsgroups/'+category+'/'+document, "r") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '20_newsgroups'
```

Comment: The error is fairly clear. `20_newsgroups` is not a directory that your program can find. 

Can you describe your folder structure a bit more clearly, then perhaps we can help you resolve this issue?

Comment: make sure `20_newsgroups` is at the same level of the python notebook your are running

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What do/don't you understand from that error message?